# Smooth "transition" from animation to transition

Tags: css, animation, hover, transition

I have an element with a looping animation in which the element bounces up and down infinitely. I want to make it so that when you hover over the element, it pauses at the peak of its bounce until you mouse out of the element, at which point it continues its animation.

I can't get it do this... I also want to make sure it does it smoothly.

Here's a poor attempt: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joelworsham/xcercbdv/)

```
.test {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite;
            animation: bounce 1s infinite;
}

div:hover {
    bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 10px;
  }
  55% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  75% {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
            transform: rotate(720deg);
  }
  80.01% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 10px;
  }
  55% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  75% {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
            transform: rotate(720deg);
  }
  80.01% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure some guru will prove me wrong... but I don't believe it's possible in pure CSS. There are no CSS event handlers to tell you when an animation has completed, etc.

Comment: So far I agree with @kthornbloom.  Pretty sure you'll have to go with some JS or jQuery to programatically add classes at certain points in the animation to get what you're looking for.  Then you run the risk of things not happening in sync and the animation getting choppy, but it should be possible with some creativity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way of affecting css property's while they play, with css.

but what comes really close to your demand is setting the `animation-play-state`

```
.test:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

stops the animation in its tracks and continues where it was paused.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/xcercbdv/1/)